# Tomcat 8 doen´t start on ubuntu 15.04 -- status=127

Tags: tomcat

I always get this message that I can't follow:

```
sudo systemctl status -l tomcat8.service
● tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since sáb 2015-05-09 00:48:07 CEST; 2h 31min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1295 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start (code=exited, status=127)

may 09 00:48:07 vaio systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
may 09 00:48:07 vaio tomcat8[1295]: [58B blob data]
may 09 00:48:07 vaio systemd[1]: tomcat8.service: control process exited, code=exited status=127
may 09 00:48:07 vaio systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Tomcat..
may 09 00:48:07 vaio systemd[1]: Unit tomcat8.service entered failed state.
may 09 00:48:07 vaio systemd[1]: tomcat8.service failed.
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You may want to investigate this site [http://tecadmin.net/install-tomcat-8-on-centos-rhel-and-ubuntu/ ]  It sounds like something missing in your install.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error when I upgraded Ubuntu and also Java (8->11). The problem was a wrong JAVA_HOME path inside the systemd module. The JAVA_HOME path had "jre/" at the end which is wrong for newer Java versions. Solution:

1. Edit `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service` and remove the trailing "jre/" of the JAVA_HOME path.
2. `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. `systemctl restart tomcat`

Comment: Worked for me! I followed a fast guide for java 8 :)

Answer (score 1):

Value 127 is returned by `/bin/sh` when the given command is not found within your `PATH` system variable and it is not a built-in shell command. In other words, the system doesn't understand your command, because it doesn't know where to find the binary you're trying to call.

for more info [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763156/127-return-code-from)

Answer (score 0):

Something must got corrupted in the installation of Tomcat.  I could not do apt-get remove tomcat8 nor apt-get purge tomcat8.  I deleted the conf folder and saved my server.xml file and webapps folders.  Then I was able to do a purge of tomcat followed by a fresh install and replacement of server.xml file with mine and I was running again.

Still do not know what corrupted the tomcat installation, but I was finally able to move on.

Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi All i got something its working for me,so please try my procedure

First goto service file in init.d

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat8
```

turn out into a execution file by adding below code at tomcat8

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Some times Java Home is not properly set at environment so Export the java home and set process id (PID) for tomcat in Catalina.sh file

```
Go to /Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
```

Add the following codes at the starting of catalina.sh file

For exporting java home, Use the respected java version to set path  i actually installed java at /usr/java/

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60 
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH JAVA_HOME
```

It the last step now add the tomcat pid for catalina add the following code after setting java home

```
CATALINA_PID=/var/run/tomcat.pid
```

Now go to terminal start the tomcat service

```
service tomcat8 start
```

We need to reload system deamon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

its worked out for me feel free to ask questions

this happens in ubuntu 15.04

> /etc/default files which enable/disable jobs
>   enable=1|0 type settings in /etc/default files should generally be avoided. The canonical way to enable/disable a service in an init system agnostic way is update-rc.d  enable|disable, which will translate to init system specific actions such as adding/removing symlinks (SysV and systemd) or creating/removing job override files (upstart). For systemd in particular, admins also often call systemctl enable|disable  directly. Thus these settings are redundant in /etc/default

source:[wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with /etc/init.d/tomcat8, java folder detection

```
find_jdks()
{
  for java_version in 9 8 7
  do
      for jvmdir in /usr/lib/jvm/java-${java_version}-openjdk-* \
                    /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-${java_version}-oracle-* \
                    /usr/lib/jvm/jre-${java_version}-oracle-*
      do
          if [ -d "${jvmdir}" ]
          then
              JDK_DIRS="${JDK_DIRS} ${jvmdir}"
          fi
      done
  done

  # Add older non multi arch installations
  JDK_DIRS="${JDK_DIRS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"
}
```

So if it can't find java under /usr/lib/jvm/jre-${java_version}-oracle-* folder it was defaulting to java-7-oracle which was for java 7 if you have installed using apt-get; you will need to fix that to default to java-8-oracle.

So, I had to change `JDK_DIRS="${JDK_DIRS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"` to `JDK_DIRS="${JDK_DIRS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"` to get this working

Comment: This problem has been fixed.  `/etc/init.d/tomcat8` now has the a line for `/usr/lib/jvm/java-${java_version}-oracle` which will pick up on `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`.    It is also possible to edit `/etc/default/tomcat8` and set the `JAVA_HOME` variable.  If you do that, it will use what is set and not try all the logic to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was setting `JAVA_HOME` in `/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh`.   The services script for tomcat `/etc/init.d/tomcat8` instead wants you set up the tomcat environment in  `/etc/default/tomcat8`.  Once I put my settings into `/etc/default/tomcat8` then deleted `/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh` tomcat started up just fine.

The reason appears to be that `/etc/init.d/tomcat8` tries to figure out which JVM is used but ignores `/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh`.  It uses the JVM info to look at the process list and see if tomcat is running.   If you use *setenv.sh*, tomcat gets started with a different JVM than the one that init.d expects.  It then can't see it in the process list and reports that it failed to start.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `JAVA_HOME path` was incorrect

change it by editing

```
/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service
```

and remove the trailing "jre/"` of the JAVA_HOME path.

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/**jre**

it will look something like this after editing

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/

now do

1. systemctl daemon-reload
2. systemctl restart tomcat

Answer (score -1):

i also got this error while starting tomcat service.in tomcat.service file when i checked [Service] section then i find that jre was not created so i remove the jre word.First it was like this "Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/jre"
i removed jre and it became like this "Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64" after that i started service.it worked.